# jQuery Validate considering trailing spaces only in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

When I try to use Jquery validator to validate email input file,  it shows "Please enter a valid email address" when I enter an extra space after a valid email. This only happens on IE, and it doesn't happen on Firefox/Chrome.  Is anyone having any ideas about this?

I am using 1.13.1 jquery validator. I wonder is this something wrong with jquery validate library itself.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Validate plugin is correctly giving you an error because a valid email address does not contain any blank spaces at the end.

Certain browsers are likely just ignoring trailing spaces when populating the `value` property of the `input` element, which would have nothing to do with this plugin.

Trailing spaces are superfluous and where most browsers correctly ignore them, Explorer does not.  Whenever the browser lets them through, the jQuery Validate plugin will flag a trailing space as invalid if the rule designates them as such.